# Map, List not generic and isEmpty function not defined caused by a maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipse show that Map, List are not generic, String class doesn't have isEmpty function. I thought that my project is configured with an old version of Java compiler but it's not. Eclipse doesn't show error with lambda function introduced in Java 8. Now we found that the problem is this dependency that we added in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mcpat.apistubs</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdc-1.1.2-stub</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why this dependency causing Eclipse to show the errors? Is it normal or a bug in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That (strange) dependency contains base Java classes in its JAR (for instance, [see here for java.util package](https://github.com/mcpat/java-microedition-libraries/tree/master/api-stubs/cdc-1.1.2-stub/src/main/java/java/util)).

So it hides the normal classes from the JDK; leading to the issue you have.